# Enneper's minimal surface

Tags: plotting, code-review

How to plot the [Enneper's minimal surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EnnepersMinimalSurface.html) like this

[image]

I tried:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u - u^3/3 + u v^2, -v - u^2 v + v^3/3, 
u^2 - v^2}, {u, -3, 3}, {v, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
Epilog -> Inset[Style["Enneper's Surface", 13], {Center, Top}, 
{Center,Bottom}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: use polar coordinates along with the Enneper-Weierstrass parametrization. (The version you have uses $z=x+iy$ instead of $z=re^{i\theta}$.)

Comment: @J.M. you are right (as usual), it does look better with the polar parameterization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick here is to use the plotting function to generate the mesh lines, but there is no way to apply a `ColorFunction` for a `MeshStyle` - mesh lines need to have a single color.  So we extract the mesh lines, break them up into pieces, and then apply the color function to them.

This could be more efficient if I didn't use `Normal` but the code would be much longer.  The first line below is used to import the Jet color map from MATLAB that was used in the OP,

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sqYFdrkY";
Normal[ParametricPlot3D[{
    r Cos[th] - r^3/3 Cos[3 th],
    -r/3 (3 Sin[th] + r^2 Sin[3 th]),
    r^2 Cos[2 th]
    }, {r, 0, 2}, {th, -π, π},
   PlotPoints -> {100, 100}, PlotRange -> All,
   Mesh -> {Subdivide[0.01, 1.99, 30],
     Subdivide[-π + .01, π + .01, 50]},
   BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1},
   PlotStyle -> None]] /. 
 Line[x__] :> ({JetCM[Rescale[#[[1, 3]], {-4.1, 4.1}]], Line[#]} & /@ 
    Partition[x, 2, 1])
```

[image]

I previously had `PlotStyle-> Opacity[0]` but noticed that the plot was incredibly slow to move around.  Changing this to `None` makes it work a lot better, so it's better to draw no surface than an invisible one.

I was really impressed by the 3D plots of minimal surfaces on Paul Nylander's page [here](https://nylander.wordpress.com/category/math/minimal-surfaces/).  You can read about the mathematics of minimal surfaces [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface).

The code on Paul's page was written for version 4.2, so it took a small amount of updating.  I will show the plots before dumping the code.  First I show the surfaces with no mesh,

[image]

Click on the image to view at higher resolution. Here are the surfaces with only mesh, mimicking what I assume is a MATLAB plotting style,

[image]

The code for these is very long, so I posted it on the Community [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/858757).  There are [easier ways](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115534/9490) to do this, but they aren't nearly as fun as this.

Comment: If you want to pursue the subject of minimal surfaces further, see [this](http://www.indiana.edu/~minimal/archive/index.html) as well.

Comment: @J.M. Those are fantastic! I wonder if I could just add them all to `Entity["Surface"]` when I start working there

Comment: Yes, the neat thing is that Weber is both a subject-matter expert and a *Mathematica* programmer. I've done some old artwork myself based on Weber's code, but I believe there's still a lot to do (e.g. more numerically stable parametrizations).

Comment: @JasonB thanks for the links. Congratulations on  job...:-)

Answer (score 6):

Jason has shown a very good way (here and on Community) to plot the Enneper surface, so let me just show my own take:

```
(* "jet" colormap *)
jet[u_?NumericQ] :=
        Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
               {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1

(* generalized Enneper surface, polar parametrization *)
enneperpolar[n_Integer, r_, θ_] := {r Cos[θ] - r^(2 n - 1)/(2 n - 1) Cos[(2 n - 1) θ],
                                    r Sin[θ] + r^(2 n - 1)/(2 n - 1) Sin[(2 n - 1) θ],
                                    (2 r^n)/n Cos[n θ]}

With[{n = 2, p = 25, q = 15}, 
     Show[ParametricPlot3D[Table[enneperpolar[n, r, θ], {θ, -π, π, 2 π/p}], {r, 0, 2},
                           ColorFunction -> (jet[#3] &), PlotRange -> All,
                           PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]]], 
          ParametricPlot3D[Table[enneperpolar[n, r, θ], {r, 0, 2, 2/q}], {θ, -π, π}, 
                           ColorFunction -> (jet[#3] &), PlotRange -> All,
                           PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]]], 
          Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Classic"] /.
     Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 1/20, rest]]
```

[image: a rather garish Enneper surface]

As Shutao notes in a comment, you might want to write a compiled version of `enneperpolar[]` if you need the speed.

---

### The Enneper-Weierstrass parametrization

In the theory of minimal surfaces, it is often convenient to represent a minimal surface in terms of two complex functions, a **Gauss map** $G$, and a **height differential** $\mathrm dh$. Taken together, these comprise the **Enneper-Weierstrass parametrization** of a minimal surface. Here is a *Mathematica* routine for generating the parametric equations of a minimal surface from its Enneper-Weierstrass parametrization:

```
ewparam[{g_, h_}, z_] := Re[Integrate[{(1/g - g), -I (1/g + g), 2} h, z]]
```

For Enneper's surface, we have $G=z^{n-1}$ and $\mathrm dh=z^{n-1}\mathrm dz$. Thus,

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[PowerExpand[
             ewparam[{z^(n - 1), z^(n - 1)}, z] /. z -> r Exp[I θ]], 
             TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], r > 0]
   {r Cos[θ] + (r^(2 n) Cos[θ - 2 n θ])/(r - 2 n r),
    r Sin[θ] + (r^(2 n) Sin[θ - 2 n θ])/(r - 2 n r),
    (2 r^n Cos[n θ])/n}
```

which can be shown to be the same as the expression for `enneperpolar[]` given earlier. (Using `z -> u + I v` yields the parametrization in the OP.)

Comment: Owing to `enneperpolar[] ` is not fast, 
it takes about 15 second on my laptop.Here is compiled version to 
speed up the performance.`enneperpolarCompiled = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {r, _Real}, {θ, _Real}}, {r Cos[θ] - r^(2 n - 1)/(2 n - 1) Cos[(2 n - 1) θ], 
    r Sin[θ] + 
     r^(2 n - 1)/(2 n - 1) Sin[(2 n - 1) θ], (2 r^n)/n Cos[n θ]}] `.Please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rb3MQ.png)

Comment: +1 Using 1-variable `ParametricPlot3D` makes it so much easier to apply the color function than the rigmarole I went through with the mesh functions. I'm totally gonna steal the idea of using `Tube` instead of `Line` though :-)

Comment: I would feel bad if you **didn't** steal it, @Jason. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Sam Carrettie](http://community.wolfram.com/web/samcarrettie) for [pointing this out](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/858777)

```
Entity["Surface", "EnneperMinimalSurface"][
 EntityProperty["Surface", "Graphics3D"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]